# JavaFX property listener ordering

Tags: java, javafx

If I add onChange listeners to a JavaFx property,

1. Are the listeners invoked in order? If I have a string property, and I then the string to "Alice" and then to "Bob", am I guaranteed to see "Alice" before I see "Bob". Actually, I don't care if I see "Alice" as long as I don't see if after I see "Bob"
2. Are the listeners invoked sequentially? Is it possible that my listener might be invoked by the "Alice" and "Bob" notification at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: your question is unclear - you seem to be asking about the order in which events are observed, rather than the order in which the listeners are called (there is only one listener in your example). I'll answer the event ordering part.

Long story short: FX properties are not thread safe. As long as you work on the property within the FX thread, the events will be triggered in order, but if you access the property from other threads, the general rules of thread safety apply.

In other words:

- if the property is only accessed on the FX thread (which is the case for a control's property that changes due to user interaction), including when you register your listener or if you programmatically set the property's value, then the events will be triggered on the FX Thread and will appear in order. So if the user types Alice then Bob, your listener will receive Alice then Bob.
- if you create a property or update a control's property manually but you start playing with threads without proper synchronization, then all bets are off. In particular, if you write :

  - `property.addListener(myListener)` in Thread A
  - `property.set("Alice")` in Thread B
  - `property.set("Bob")` in Thread C

  your listener may or may not see "Alice" and it may or may not see "Bob". It may actually see "Alice" but not "Bob" and it may see "Bob" but not "Alice".

Comment: Basically, I was asking for property.addListner(myListener), which thread the listener will run on. It sounds like the listener will run on the FXThread (unless I'm missing something), which solves my problem.

Comment: If you don't set the properties yourself you can safely assume that your listener will be called on the fx thread. If in doubt you can check in your listener that your are on the fx thread.